# Search indexing but not returning results in Claims authenticated web apps

Tags: search-results, forms-authentication, claims-based-auth

I have the following setup, but even though the crawler successfully indexes over 7000 items, I don't get any search results from the Default zone or the extended one:

- Default zone: Claims Authenticated, NTLM enabled, Anonymous Access enabled
- Extended extranet zone: Claims Authenticated, FBA with custom login form

The search service application has already been rebuilt and associated with the web app, I have made sure that the default content access account (AD sp_search account) has a "Full Read" User Policy on the web app and has read permission in the content database.

I have tried the following powershell script but also with no luck:

```
$searchApp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication "Search"
$searchApp.SetProperty("ForceClaimACLs",1)
```

I would expect to see errors in the ULS but can't find any.

I have also tried re-adding user permissions since enabling Claims Authentication so that it resolves the Claims username with no effect.

Can anyone help please? Thank you

Comment: It now appears that the problem is caused by the ?u= parameter on the search results page, which is presumably linked to the way the scopes work. If I remove this parameter, I get search results (from the top level).

I have made sure that the Alternate Access Mappings are correct, the Content Source is configured to crawl the default zone URL and I have reset the index and performed a full crawl.

Comment: I have also read that there could be problems if using a mixture of http and https in Alternate Acess Mappings, but this is unlikely to be the case since it stopped working as a result of configuring Claims Authentication. Still having the same problem!

Comment: Also read that in WSS 3.0 there were issues with OOTB contextual scopes such as "This Site" not working for lists with spaces in their names(!). However, search was working fine before Claims.

Comment: Another thing to note - it's impossible to have the Default Zone use Classic Mode Authentication - authentication type is set for the entire web application, so it must be set to Claims in order for the extended FBA site to work. In fact, the only reason it was extended in the first place was to try to avoid this problem with search!

Comment: I have now found out that Enterprise search features are enabled on the web application. I'm not sure what effect (if anything) this has on things though.

Comment: Well, I've now given up and just disabled the scopes drop-down! If anyone comes up with an answer, please post here.